# Javascript: Check if a string is a valid function name before calling eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

Is it possible to check if a string is a valid function name before calling eval?

```
var fnString = $('#fnInput').val()

// is there any way I can check if fnString is a valid function name 
// before calling the following line:

eval(fnString + '()');
```

I understand the risks of using `eval()`, this is a private project that will not be available to the public.

Comment: Depending on the scope, you could do `typeof(window[fnString]) == "function"`

Comment: Was just going to suggest that ^^ but change `window` for the relevant scope (object)

Comment: Additionally, you should rethink the design of your application. You should not have to do this kind of check.

Comment: also shouldn't need `eval()`

Comment: @charlietfl how else would I run functions from them being typed into an input box?

Comment: After you check valid string do `window[fnString]()` or `someObject[fnString]()`

Comment: @Jimmery Well not knowing the project it's hard to answer, but if you just have a list of functions the user can run you could make it a select element instead.

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the suggestion - I will use this instead of eval() - if you add this as an answer I will mark you as correct

Comment: @George the project needs to be versatile with different libraries - having to hardcode in all the function names is an inelegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your scope you can do something like this:

```
var fnString = $('#fnInput').val();
if(typeof window[fnString] === "function") {
    window[fnString]();
}
```

Comment: No need for triple equal since typeof always return string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` to get the type.

```
if (eval(`typeof ${fnString}`) == "function") {
    eval(`${fnString}()`);
}
```